# Cutting out dictionary file defined regions of a FASTA gene sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta, dna-sequence

Very new to Python and coding in general so feel free to laugh. I want to use a txt file (dict) in the following format with genes in the first column and the region of the sequence (start position  end position)

```
ORFB    21563 25384
ORF3a   25393 26220
ORF2a   26245 26472
ORF10   29558 29674
S   21563 25384
E   26245 26472
```

to read a FASTA DNA file from Genbank (GENE.fasta.txt) so that the output would be the gene name and then the sequence between start and stop for each gene.
Here is the beginning of the FASTA file

> MN908947.3 Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2 isolate Wuhan-Hu-1, complete genome
> ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAA
> CGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAAC
> TAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCTGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTG
> TTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTCGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTC
> CCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTAC
> GTGGCTTTGGAGACTCCGTGGAGGAGGTCTTATCAGAGGCACGTCAACATCTTAAAGATGGCACTTGTGG
> CTTAGTAGAAGTTGAAAAAGGCGTTTTGCCTCAACTTGAACAGCCCTATGTGTTCATCAAACGTTCGGAT
> GCTCGAACTGCACCTCATGGTCATGTTATGGTTGAGCTGGTAGCAGAACTCGAAGGCATTCAGTACGGTC
> GTAGTGGTGAGACACTTGGTGTCCTTGTCCCTCATGTGGGCGAAATACCAGTGGCTTACCGCAAGGTTCT
> TCTTCGTAAGAACGGTAATAAAGGAGCTGGTGGCCATAGTTACGGCGCCGATCTAAAGTCATTTGACTTA

So for ORFB 21563 25384, I want to select and print the DNA code between 21563 and 25384 for ORF3a  25393 26220 I want to select and print between 25393 and 26220 etc.

I tried the following.

with open('dict.txt') as f:
ranges = {ID: (int(start), int(stop)) for ID, start, stop in map(lambda s: s.strip().split(), f)}

```
from Bio import SeqIO
with open ('GENE.fasta.txt') as handle:
    out = [r[slice(*ranges[r.id])] for r in SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta')]

with open('output.fasta', 'w') as handle:
    SeqIO.write(out, handle, 'fasta')
```

But I keep getting KeyError: 'MN908947.3'
Thanks!

Comment: what does "no luck" mean? your code looks, at first glance, like it should work fine

Comment: Sorry about that. I I keep getting KeyError: 'MN908947.3'  The FASTA file is MN908947.3 Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2 isolate Wuhan-Hu-1, complete genome

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the map to the file object.
You have to do something like this:

```
with open('dict.txt') as f:
    ranges = {
        ID: (int(start), int(stop))
        for ID, start, stop
        in map(lambda line: line.strip().split(), f.readlines())
    }
```

The readlines method returns list of lines in your file. And maybe is more readable to use list comprehension: `[line.strip().split() for line in f.readlines()]`

I hope I helped

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried that, but I keep getting KeyError: 'MN908947.3'

Comment: The FASTA file is MN908947.3 Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2 isolate Wuhan-Hu-1, complete genome

Comment: I dont think this addresses the OP question unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

apparently MN908947.3 in not an ID that you built with your first step

so when you try and do `ranges[r.id]` it does not exist and throws an error

you could *maybe* do something more like

```
with open ('GENE.fasta.txt') as handle:
    out = [r[slice(*ranges[r.id])] for r in SeqIO.parse(handle, 'fasta') if r.id in ranges]
```

this will only get ranges that you identified in your first step ... it is possible you are not building your ids correctly, but there is not enough info in your question to assert anything other than that is also a possibility of why it might be failing (ie if you think MN908947.3 is in your first step)